# How to use browserSync with gulp in angular2 app with angular cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, gulp-browser-sync

I'm developing an Angular 2 app using angular cli. I'm also using gulp as a task runner in the project. I want to use BrowserSync with gulp instead of the default ember live reload plugin that angular cli provides with. I have tried using proxy option in gulp browserSync to that of the default ng serve port ie: 4200. But then when gulp is running, I'm unable to run the project (ng serve). So can anyone please help me with this problem as I want to run browserSync with gulp. This might be a very n00b question as I'm new to gulp and angular, but help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:** I was able to connect to BrowserSync using gulp but then the changes that I had made weren't getting updated either in the /dist folder or in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're still using `ng serve`, then you should know that all the files are only compiled in-memory. So there are no file changes for BrowserSync to reload.

Instead, use `ng build --watch`, which will watch for file changes and automatically build to your `/dist` folder. Then use BrowserSync to serve from there.